# Embed YouTube And Auto Play With Full Screen?

Tags: youtube

Here's what I'm interested in doing.  I haven't been able to figure it out so I thought I would ask for advice.

1)  Take the link for a YouTube video in the iFrame format they provide.
2)  Put this in a post on my blog.
3)  When I send someone to this particular post I would like for the video to automatically play and not only that, play in full screen mode.

Is this something I can do?  If so can you please tell me how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use autoplay=1 as a parameter in src of your video -

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="480" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zGPuazETKkI?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

For more details follow the link - https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: That works great for auto play.  How about a parameter so that the video will display full screen?  This one plays in 480x390 window.